# converting result's error code to a string

Tags: rust

I want to open a file, but in the case that my program fails to open it I want to print an error message to the user and exit early.

```rust
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let file = "something.txt";
    let file = match File::open(file) {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(e) => {
            //err_string is not a real function, what would you use?
            println!("failed to open file: {}", e.err_string());
            return;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print an error message to the user and exit early:
1. You may use `File::open("something.txt")?`, try the following example (**No panic**, just print an error message):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = File::open("something.txt")?;
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;
    assert_eq!(contents, "Hello, world!");
    Ok(())
}
```

Output (on error):

```
Error: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }
```

---

2. Using `.expect("msg")`: **Panics** if the value is an Err, with a panic message including the passed message, and the content of the Err (**developer friendly**, since shows the file name and line number):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("something.txt").expect("failed to open file");
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents)
        .expect("failed to read file");
    assert_eq!(contents, "Hello, world!");
}
```

Output (on error):

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to open file: 
Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', 
src/main.rs:17:20
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

---

3. **No panic**, just print an error message:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut file = match File::open("something.txt") {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("failed to open file: {}", e);
            return;
        }
    };

    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents)
        .expect("failed to read file");
    assert_eq!(contents, "Hello, world!");
}
```

Output (on error):

```
failed to open file: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

you can just do:

```
println!("failed to open file: {}", e);
```

it will convert it to a string automatically